Paging fails at 15,30, and 50 items per page
For a similar discussion (though the issue appears to have been resolved over there), see this Meta.Biology post.
To reproduce:

Go to the Questions link/tab
Select the last page (in our case, page #9 with 50 questions per page)
Now, try to go back the page before that one (page #8)

I get the following:

Unlike when I had the problem on Biology.SE, this seems to occur with 15 or 30 items per page selected as well.
I'm using Chrome 20, but I can reproduce the problem on Firefox 13.

Status no repro here, chrome latest. Do you have any tags ignored?

@BenBrocka No tags ignored.  Others were able to reproduce it on Bio when I had trouble with it over there.  Hmmm.

Yes, I seem to get the problem on 6, 7, and 8, but not 5 or 9. (ubuntu 11.10; chrome 21)

@JeromyAnglim Exactly, and then everything that was supposed to be on 9 is on 5, and I think it progresses back from there.

Never fear, I have Tim Stone on this issue! He'll either determine the cause or get the team's attention :-)

@JoshGitlin Excellent, thanks.

OK, that is most decidedly odd. Investigating!

What's really going to bake your noodle... when I can get page 6 to load... the content is page 9. Something is not right...

Something was a bit broken here re caching/paging. I've made some short-term fixes while I investigate; it should work OK now.

Awesome, thanks Marc!

Thanks for taking care of that so quickly Marc!

I have asked about this on Meta Stack Overflow, the "mother meta" for all the Stack Exchange sites. Hopefully we can get an answer there (if the team doesn't also see it here)
EDIT: Marc Gravell♦ has fixed this bug. (See his answer)

Any rep you get above 50, I expect in dollars in my PayPal account.

Does PayPal do conversions from Unicorn Dollars now? :-)

Don't make me send Mien after you.
